# How to let Cakephp 3 choose database connection by Apache environment variable

Tags: cakephp, deployment, environment

I'm working with cakephp v3 and want to install the application in two different environments, one for development and one for production use.  Both installations should consist of exactly the same files (and file contents), so I could use 'git' or 'svn' to easily deploy the application.

If both environments are hosted on the same machine, I need different database settings (so that the development env uses its own 'testing' DB).  I thought of configuring two 'Datasources' in `app.php`, the 'default' one for production and a `development'.

But how can I switch between both sources?

To be more specific: Currently I define the following environment variable in my Apache config for the development environment:

```
SetEnv CAKEPHP_DEBUG 1
```

Then I changed the definition of 'debug' in the `app.php` file like this:

```
'debug' => (bool)getenv('CAKEPHP_DEBUG'),
```

This enables DEBUG mode only on the development machine.  Now I also want to switch database configuration in the same easy way.

(I already found some solutions for cakephp v2, but all of them are pretty old and I'm not sure what's the best way to do it in cakephp v3.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration) says

> You can define as many connections as you want in your configuration
>   file. You can also define additional connections at runtime using
>   Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::config().

So I guess you can check the value of debug in `AppController` `beforeFilter` and change the default database connection

**AppController.php**

```
if(Configure::read('debug') == 1)
{
    ConnectionManager::config('default', [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'dev_server',
        'username' => 'dev_username',
        'password' => 'dev_passwd',
        'database' => 'development',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
    ]);
}
```

I think you can do something similar in app.php using the ternary operator

**app.php**

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => getenv('CAKEPHP_DEBUG')== 1 ? [ /* debug params */ ] : [ /* default params */]
    ...
]
```

But somehow it don't seem the 'clean' way to do it

I think that a cleaner way would be to set both configurations in app.php and then in appController choose what configurations to use

**app.php**

```
'Datasources' => [
    'debug' => [ /* debug params */ ],
    'default' => [ /* default params */]
]
```

**Table file**

```
public static function defaultConnectionName() {
    if(Configure::read('debug') == 1)
        return 'debug';
    return 'default';
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks!  However, I'd prefer putting the DB config in app.php instead of AppController.php.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  The ternary operator works perfectly!  The solution with `defaultConnectionName' does not work: if I read the docs correctly, this method must be overwritten in every *Table class and I don't want to duplicate the code so often...

Comment: I guess you can create a parent table and let all others tables inherit from it. But maybe it's over complicated

Comment: Another way would be to load different/additional configuration files [**in your bootstrap**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.6/config/bootstrap.php#L67-L80), depending on the environment. Something along the lines of this for example: **https://gist.github.com/ndm2/33896a7bf461ac84df6265f15099291f**

Comment: @ndm in that case how should the config file be? If I understand well it should redefine/overwrite the Datasources array, right?

Comment: @ndm your comment should be an answer to this question. It's a better solution than the accepted one as we can easily add new environments (test, uat, ...)