# CakePHP3 switch database connection based on enviroment

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to switch my default datasource based on the enviroment, or app domain.

```
'Datasources' => [
  'default' => [
      'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
      'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => 'localhost'
  ],

  'local' => [
      'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
      'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => 'localhost'
  ], 

  'stage' => [
      'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
      'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => 'localhost'
  ] 
],
```

Has CakePHP3 some logic to handle this kaind of thing? I cannot found anything useful in te documentation.

Thanks,
Mauri.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let Cakephp 3 choose database connection by Apache environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864867/how-to-let-cakephp-3-choose-database-connection-by-apache-environment-variable)

Answer (score 1):

When all the table on each db is same

You can use ConnectionManager::alias():

From Controller :

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

```
if($somecase == "local") {
   ConnectionManager::alias('local', 'default');
else if($somecase == "stage") {
   ConnectionManager::alias('stage', 'default');
}
else {
  //cake will use default
}
```

more reference : http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_alias